# Mongodb 2 sequentially queries to 1 collection with limit

Tags: mongodb

I want to query 1 collection with 2 different queries and I don't know how to aggregate it. In result I want to achieve 8 entries, 4 from each query. Please give me some advice.

These are my queries

```
db.collection('Tests').find('something1').sort({_id:-1}).limit(4)
db.collection('Tests').find('something2').sort({_id:-1}).limit(4)
```

Tried to use $or and $match, but limit is working at the end and limiting all the documents.

```
db.getCollection('Tests').aggregate([ 
{
    $match: {
    $or: [
        {some:"M1"},
        {some:"M2"}
   ]
  }
}])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use $facet to achieve this like the following aggregate query:

```
db.getCollection('Tests').aggregate([ 
{
  $facet: {
    query1: [
      {
        $match: { some:"M1"},
      },
      { $limit: 4 }
    ],
    query2: [
      {
        $match: { some:"M2"},
      },
      { $limit: 4 }
    ],
  }
}
}]);
```

**Note:** This query won't perform good if the data size is large. For large data sets, it's better to execute separate queries in parallel.

In case you are using Node.js, you can use something like the following:

```
Promise.all([ db.collection('Tests').find('something1').sort({_id:-1}).limit(4), db.collection('Tests').find('something2').sort({_id:-1}).limit(4) ]).then(results => /* use results here*/).catch(error => /*handle error here*/);
```

Comment: How to execute queries in parallel in better way, without decresing performance?

Comment: In case you are using Node.js, you can use something like the following:

Promise.all([  db.collection('Tests').find('something1').sort({_id:-1}).limit(4),
db.collection('Tests').find('something2').sort({_id:-1}).limit(4) ]).then(results => /* use results here*/).catch(error => /*handle error here*/);